# Extracting geometry in geopandas (worldmap) into my dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, geopandas

My dataframe has a country name but not the location (coordinates) so I am trying to extract that from geopandas worldmap. Does anyone know how to get the geometry column from world geopandans to match with the country name of my drink.csv dataframe in order to create a new column in my drinks.csv

**world data from geopandas**
[image]

**my data set = drinks.csv**
[image: my data set]

[![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0qp8.jpg
  [2]:][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p4O5.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p4O5.jpg) https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGr3O.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use indexing and slicing with column values:

```
# set index of the country shapes to the name of the country
country_shapes_newindex = country_shapes.set_index('name')

# slice on the country shapes using the names of the countries from your drinks dataframe.
# the result is a DataFrame, select the geomtry column, and get their values.
# finally store this in a new column in your drinks DataFrame
drinks['geometry'] = country_shapes_newindex.loc[drinks['Country'].values]['geometry'].values
```